# Database tables have no foreign keys

Tags: magento2, database, foreign-key

I have taken over a **Magento 2 website** and I have noticed quiet a few tables with **no foreign keys** e.g. a table is missing `CONSTRAING 'CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE_ID_STORE_ID' FOREIGN KEY ('store_id') REFERENCES 'store' ('store_id') ON DELETE CASCADE`.

I haven't come across this issue before and I am not sure if simply adding the missing foreign keys back would fix all of the issues (`assuming I could find all of the missing keys`). I know there is a database repair tool for Magento 1.9 and I've seen one or two suggestions to run from the CLI the database scheme update. The keys have been missing for the last few months and quiet a few records would have been **added/deleted** since then.

I am a bit unsure how to start fixing this issue. Create blank magento site and import the current database data to it, or add the missing keys.